# MySQL Engine vs. Charset

Tags: php, database, customization

I am attempting to have my plugin create a new table.  I am fairly new to SQL.  I have found two different method for creating tables:

#### Method I

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cool_table';
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    [command to set up columns go here]
    ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
```

#### Method II

```
if ( ! empty($wpdb->charset) )
    $charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $wpdb->charset";
if ( ! empty($wpdb->collate) )
    $charset_collate .= " COLLATE $wpdb->collate";

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'cool_table';

$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
    [command to set up columns go here]
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB {$charset_collate};";
```

What is the benefit of setting the default charset vs. setting the ENGINE when creating a new table?

Comment: This is a MySQL question but the charset and the database engine are different animals. Your two blocks of code do different things.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do these two pieses of code not both set up a SQL statement that can be used with the dbDelta() function in order to create a new table in the database?

Comment: But the second-- the `ENGINE` one-- changes the database engine to `InnoDB` for the table created. The first creates the table using the server default database engine, which used to be `MYISAM` but I heard a rumor that that was changing.

Comment: Yea my understanding is that the most recent version of MySQL is using InnoDB as the default.  When I specify the engine here, does it change it for the entire database or just the table?  Also, is there a reason for me to set the default charset when creating a table?  What are the implications of this?